# Changing from BG Update Downloader to Update Downloader with silent version check

Tags: install4j

Our application currently has "Background update downloader" configured for the update checks and installation. We have a few problems in this approach with the User community and we are working on making the update transparent to the User. To this end we are trying out the "Update downloader with the silent version check".

The Users currently have the Client with the "Background update downloader" installed on their machines.e.g xxx.y1 Now the update has the "silent version check" built in with the version xxx.y2. Now the update versions are found out currently and an update is triggered. However, the update continues in the "Background update" mode and not via the GUI Layout "silent version check".

If we unintall version xxx.y1 and reinstall the client directly with the version xxx.y2 and then have a version xxx.y3 updated, this works correctly in the "silent version check" application mode.

The guess here is that the files present in the .install4j (e.g i4jparams.conf,etc)in the initial installation have references to the BG Update Downloader.

Is there a way around this (or) is uninstallation and installation again is the only way forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update will always be performed by the currently installed version which in your case has the background upgrade downloader configured.

After an upgrade (or uninstallation and new installation), the new update downloader will be used, in your case the one with the silent version check.

There is no way to change the update downloader for the currently installed version.